# What happens internally when we run a kSQL query?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am entirely new to Apache Kafka and kSQL. I was having a question in my mind and I tried to find out the answer but I failed to do so.

My current understanding is that the events that are getting generated from the producer are being stored in the Kafka internally in the topics in serialized form (0s and 1s). If I create a Kafka stream to consume the data and after that, If I run kSQL query let's say to use the COUNT() function so will the output of that query persist in the Kafka topics.

If that the case will it not be a storage cost?

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, it runs a Kafka Streams topology.

Any persisted streams or aggregated tables, in your case, indeed occupy storage.